# In iPhone: Page is moved up when a button is clicked in overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

Page is moved up in iPhone when a button is clicked in an overlay.

This issue arose in calendar component. Upon selection of date in calendar, I am focusing calendar text field. There is no issue if I select date from first row of calendar. But if I select from last row, then the page is scrolled up and my calendar input field is not visible. I need to scroll to view the field.

If overlay area overlaps with iPhone keypad area(Assume if it is popped up), then page is being moved up if any button is clicked in that overlap area.

Simplified the scenario with just two buttons. Page will be moved up if second button is clicked.

Could you help with this issue other than applying scrollTo(0 ,0)

```js
         $('#btn0').on('click', function(){
           $('.absDiv').show();
        });
        $('.item').on('click', function(){
           $('.absDiv').hide();
           $('#text1').focus();
        });
```

```css
            .absDiv{
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 0px;
                height:400px;
                border:1px solid black;
                z-index:1;
                width: 300px;
            }
            input{
                font-size: 16px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative">
        <div><input type="text" id="text1" />
         <button id="btn0"> Launch overlay</button></div>
        <div class="absDiv" style="display:none">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 200px">
            <button id="btn1" class="item" style="margin-bottom: 50px;"> Btn1</button></div>
            <button id="btn2" class="item"> Btn2</button>
            
        </div>
      </div>
```